# Contextfree language or not? I can write a grammar but not use pumping lemma

Tags: context-free-grammar, pumping-lemma

I have the language:
    L = {0^i 1^i | i >= 0}

The grammar that describes it proves it is a context free language:
    S -> 0S1
       |  e

If a language is context free, Pumping Lemma should hold. I can however not get it to work, no matter what i choose to "pump", i will get a mix of 0's and 1's, e.g. 0101.

Am i correct that it is really a context free language? If so, can you give an example of using Pumping Lemma?

Comment: For CF languages, you choose *two* strings to "pump" (express a string in the language as uvxyz, then pump *both* v and y).  So it should be trivial to choose v and y to meet the conditions of the CF pumping lemma and make the proof work in this example. (Hint: x will be the null string.)

Comment: Also, you should be aware that, although you can use the CFPL to prove a language is *not* context free, the proof does *not* work in the other direction.

Comment: I have s = uvxyz, can you show how you want to split a string in L so it can be pumped? Even if i choose v or y to be empty, not both of them can be, and i will eventually pump something up. I can choose too pump only 0's, getting more 0's than 1's - only 1's, getting more 1's than 0's - both 0's and 1's getting me ...0101... when pumping.

Comment: have you tried v='0', x=e, y='1'?  v and y are 'pumped' an equal number of times if you're using CFPL.

Comment: @KentMuntheCaspersen (1) These lemmas can be used to determine if a particular language is **not** in a given language class. However, they **cannot be used to determine if a language is in a given class** , since satisfying the **pumping lemma is a necessary, but not sufficient, condition for class membership**. [Link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pumping_lemma) (2) Read: [Pumping lemma for CFG doubt](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/10873/pumping-lemma-for-cfg-doubt)

Comment: When v='0', x=e, y='1', I had wrongly figured out that this would give a string of the form 010101... which is not in L. Thanks for your answer this cleared my mind. I understand that Pumping Lemma holds for all context free languages and also some that are not context free, thus you cannot prove that a language is context free by using Pumping Lemma. However, given that we know the language L is context free, Pumping Lemma should still hold. Therefor there must be a solution as found by @JimLewis.

Comment: @KentMuntheCaspersen you comment is confusing to me :( .. Is it too me?

Comment: Partly, you say that the Pumping Lemma cannot be used to show that a particular language is context free. You are right, but that is not my concern. In this case i already know that the language is context free and therefor Pumping Lemma should hold. @JimLewis found a correct solution to how Pumping Lemma could hold on this language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can describe a language with a context free grammar, then the language is context free. It would be difficult to prove a language is context free using the pumping lemma, because even if you find a string that can be pumped, there still might be a string that cannot be pumped.

You usually use the pumping lemma to prove a language is *not* context free. Because all you need is one example of a string that cannot be pumped.

Here is an example of a string in L = {0^i 1^i | i >= 0} and how it can be pumped.

string w=01, can be split as follows:

```
u = empty   
v = 0  
x = empty  
y = 1   
z = empty
```

u v^i x y^i z is in L for every i >= 0

Comment: It is right that pumping lemma is mostly used to prove that a language is context free. You say it might be difficult to prove a language is context free using the pumping lemma. This is in fact impossible since pumping lemma also holds for some languages which are not context-free. In this case we already know the language L is context-free (I wrote a grammar for it), and you have just shown a string that can be pumped, which was what I asked for. Thank you.